# Pentaho: Update a record of database using public parameter

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

Using Pentaho, I would like to update records of database with the value of some of public parameters of the transformation. I know that I can use the value of parameters in some steps such as `Table input` or `Database Join` by checking the `Replace variable` option. However, I cannot find any way to pass value of public parameters of the transformation in order to use in `Update` step. Can anyone help me with that?

For clarificattion: I want to use the parameter which is defined here [image: Public parameters of transformation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use public parameter of transformation, `Get Variable` step can be used.

Comment: Yup, that's one way to do it